# Trying to use caml query to get match with lookup field

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, caml-query

I want to match the current user with a lookup field in a specific list. It seems something is wrong with my caml query.

```
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var web = clientContext.get_web();
    var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle("Managers");
    var currentUser = context.get_web().get_currentUser();
    var currentUserLoginName = currentUser.get_loginName();
    var currentUserId = currentUser.get_id();
    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\'Employee\'LookupId=\'True\'>' +
        '<Value Type=\'Lookup\'>' + currentUserId + '</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>');

    var listItemCollection = list.getItems(camlQuery);

    clientContext.load(listItemCollection);
```

Where is my mistake?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: what's the error you see?

Comment: Actually there isn't any error . It just won't return any results although i have records with the lookup field value to current user

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var list = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle("ListName");
var cQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
var camlXML = "<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Author' LookupId='True'/><Value Type='Lookup'>" + _spPageContextInfo.userId + "</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>";
cQuery.set_viewXml(camlXML);
var listitems = list.getItems(cQuery);
context.load(listitems);
context.executeQueryAsync(function() {
        var enumerator = listitems.getEnumerator();
        while (enumerator.moveNext()) {
            var item = enumerator.get_current().get_fieldValues();
            console.log(item);
        }
    },
    function(s, a) {
        console.error(a.get_message());
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

To match current user you can directly use below CAML query :

```
<Where>
  <Eq>
    <FieldRef Name="Employee" />
    <Value Type="Integer">
      <UserID Type='Integer'/>
    </Value>
  </Eq>
</Where>
```

I have made some changes to your code. Refer below code. This should work :

```
function getData(){

    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var list = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle("Managers");
    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.set_viewXml("<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Employee' /><Value Type='Integer'><UserID Type='Integer'/></Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>");
    listItemCollection = list.getItems(camlQuery);

    clientContext.load(listItemCollection);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(getDataSuccess, getDataFailed);

}

function getDataSuccess(){

    var listItemEnumerator = listItemCollection.getEnumerator();
    while(listItemEnumerator.moveNext()){
         var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();

         // further code 

    }
}

function getDataFailed(sender, args){

    // failure handler

}
```